# Translation of array attributes from validator

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-validation, laravel-localization

How to translate keys from the validator attributes when it is array?

For example:

Here is validator with arrays `'image.author'` and `'image.book'`.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    'image.author' => 'required',
    'image.book' => 'required',
]);
```

On `validation.php` exist these attributes.

```
'attributes' => [
    'image.author' => 'image of author',
    'image.book' => 'image of book',
],
```

If i use tinker to debug:
`__('validation.attributes.image.author');`

> "validation.attributes.image.author"

And the output corret should be:

> "image of author"

Answer (score 0):

'author' and 'book' should be indexes of the 'images' index in the validation attributes array.

```
'attributes' => [
    'image' => [
        'author' => 'image of author',
        'book' => 'image of book',
    ],
],
```

This does not work in Laravel 8 but only from Laravel 9 and above.

```
 __('validation.attributes.image.author')
```

Results in `'validation.attributes.image.author'` in Laravel 8 and it results in `image of author` in Laravel 9 and above. See sandboxes below.

Laravel 8: https://phpsandbox.io/n/validation-array-l8-8euec#routes/web.php

Laravel 9: https://phpsandbox.io/n/validation-array-l9-piamq#routes/web.php

Laravel 10: https://phpsandbox.io/n/validation-array-l10-muf1l#routes/web.php

Comment: this won't work for the VALIDATOR (Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given) but works for the TRANSLATION (__(validation.attributes.image.author)).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to translate these were by:

```
trans('validation.attributes')['image.author']; //'image of author'
trans('validation.attributes')['image.book']; //'image of book'
```

The `trans('validation.attributes')` returns array with all keys present.

Furthermore,in L10, they have added the translation of index(`*`). So `image.*.author` will be translated too. Here are the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#error-message-indexes-and-positions).